# stackexchange.com missing cookie consent logic

Tags: bug, status-review, stackexchange.com, cookies, gdpr

There appear to be two bugs on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) regarding GDPR/CookieLaw and cookie consent:

1. There's no cookie consent dialog, similar to the rest of the Stack Exchange network
2. You can't manage cookie consent (possibly because the cookie consent logic is missing)

Regarding the second issue, I'm referring specifically to the **Cookie Settings** footer link.

You can see the different behavior if you click **Company** > **Cookie Settings** in:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/#footer
- https://stackexchange.com/#footer

Comment: It's worth noting, that meta does not have this issue, nor have I seen this issue on other sites from the network.

Comment: It appears to be missing a Js folder that the other sites have.

Comment: What does "CookieLaw" refer to? Is the intent a common noun? Or [this website](https://www.cookielaw.org/about-us/) (that has a list of jurisdictions)? Or to a *particular* jurisdiction outside the EU? Or something else?

Comment: Informally called "The Cookie Law", [Privacy and Electronic Communications Directive / ePrivacy Directive / ePD (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications_Directive_2002) was a predecessor (but not replacement) to [GDPR (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). Among other things, it requires transparency to the use of cookies within the EU and its citizens.

Comment: Regarding [the website](https://www.cookielaw.org/about-us/), it is just a provider for the implementation of the regulations mentioned above. It is worth noting, that since 2002, the "cookie law" has seen similar legislation in other areas of the world.

Comment: Regarding the particularities of jurisdiction in and out of the EU, I can't really comment. The bug, as presented in the question, is regarding the fact that the cookie consent exists throughout the stackexchange network, but is missing on the main stackexchange.com site. Separately, the intent would seem to be that the consent exist, since the footer link implies managing cookies and does nothing.